# Changing version from MAJOR.MINOR to MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH

Tags: android, version-control, version

I have an android app on playstore and currently, we are using MAJOR.MINOR (eg. 2.1) version format. 
I would like to change this to MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format. How do I do that? Any specific procedure for that or simply add PATCH version to version code in next release (eg. 2.1.1). Please suggest.

Comment: looks like you are talking about `vaesionName`. It is just a human-readable string of your version, which can be anything, including even words:`twooneone` for example. Google Play totally does not care what you write in it. So you can just start adding a patch there straight away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your app-level `build.gradle`, the `versionName` property is a String and can be defined in any format you like, for example:

- Major minor e.g. `2.1`
- Major minor patch e.g. `2.1.1`
- Major minor patch + commitHash e.g. `2.1.1+a2b3c4d5`
- Or any other format as defined in [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/)

The `versionCode`, however, must remain an integer which must be greater than the previous version. Personally I determine my version codes by multiplying each part by a factor:

- Major x 10,000
- Minor x 100
- Patch x 1

So a `versionName` of 2.1.1 would have a `versionCode` of 20101. This allows for 100 patches and 100 minor increments, starting from 0.

Answer (score 2):

You simply add the new version name.

That version name is completely dependent on you and serves no purpose internally, other than to make a readable String of text for users and developers.

Internally, all that matters is the version code, so you can rename the version name however you want without any worries.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469080/michael-dodd) response, You can implement this way.

> Within your app-level `build.gradle`, the `versionName` property is a
>   String and can be defined in any format you like, for example:
>
> - Major minor e.g. `2.1`
> - Major minor patch e.g. `2.1.1`
> - Major minor patch + commitHash e.g. `2.1.1+a2b3c4d5`
> - Or any other format as defined in [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/)
>
> The `versionCode`, however, must remain an integer which must be
>   greater than the previous version. Personally I determine my version
>   codes by multiplying each part by a factor:
>
> - Major x 10,000
> - Minor x 100
> - Patch x 1
>
> So a `versionName` of 2.1.1 would have a `versionCode` of 20101. This
>   allows for 100 patches and 100 minor increments, starting from 0.

in `build.gradle` define 3 variable and use like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    def majorVersion = 2
    def minorVersion = 1
    def patchVersion = 1

    versionCode majorVersion * 10000 + minorVersion * 100 + patchVersion
    versionName "${majorVersion}.${minorVersion}.${patchVersion}"

    ...
}
```